# open source gui diff program with file type preset for linux

Tags: linux, open-source, diff

I used to use [Examdiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) on windows which is great because it shows diff with respect to the file type like comparing JSOON or sort INI files before comparing.

On Linux I found beyond compare which does everything that Examdiff does, but not as easy as Examdiff, also it is not open source.
So I need a *GUI* `diff` program that:

1. Has plugins (file type preset like file sorting)
2. does folder compare
3. preferably open source

**UPDATE:**
To explain what I mean with plugins I will give two examples

First I will compare the following files:

1. *1.json*:

   ```
   {
     "name": "test app",
     "version": "0.1",
     "release_date": "2_2_2002",
     "kernel": "4.14",
     "username": "root",
     "password": "1234",
   }
   ```
2. *2.json*

   ```
   {"name": "test app","version": "0.1","release_date": "2_2_2002","kernel": "4.14","username": "root","password": "1234",}
   ```

You can see that these JSON files are identical in content except that the first one is indented properly (beautified) while the second one is minified.

So if I run any comparison tool on these files I would get many differences.

Running `meld`:

[image: running meld]

while if I run [Examdiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) on these files it detects that these are JSON files so it uses a plugin and passes these files to a [small utility](http://www.raboof.com/projects/tidyjson/) that beautifies these files before comparing(All this is done under the hood of course).So after comparing it shows that the files are identical

[image]

The second example is INI files:

1. *1.ini*

   ```
   [info]
   ShortName=EN

   [main]
   var1=Yes
   var2=No
   var3=Abort
   var4=Ignore
   var5=OK
   var6=Cancel
   var7=Retry
   var8=All
   var9=Help
   ```
2. *2.ini*

   ```
   [main]
   var1=Yes
   var6=Cancel


   var5=OK

   var9=Help

   var2=No
   var3=Abort

   var4=Ignore
   var7=Retry
   var8=All



   [info]
   ShortName=EN
   ```

In INI files, the order of the *key=value* pairs doesn't matter as long as they are in the same sections and empty lines also don't matter

so again running `meld` shows a lot of differences:

[image]

while running [Examdiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) shows that they are identical (this time it uses another plugin which relies on a utility called INIsorter)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but in the meantime some filters can be simulated with [`bash` process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) and various utils:

1. For *.json* files, using [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq):

   ```
   meld  <(mlr --json cat 1.json | jq -M '.' ) \
         <(mlr --json cat 2.json | jq -M '.' )
   ```
2. For *.ini* files, using [`crudini`](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/):

   ```
   meld <(crudini --get --format=lines 1.ini|sort) \
        <(crudini --get --format=lines 2.ini|sort)
   ```

One defect of such methods is that `meld` doesn't display the filenames, (*1.json*, *etc.*), it displays the *process substitution* device numbers from which one must deduce the corresponding filename.

Comment: I'd suppose that `jq` alone would be sufficient, (*i.e.* `jq -M 1.json`), but without `mlr` it returns the error "*parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 8, column 1*".

Answer (score 0):

## Meld

I don't know Examdiff and thus, I don't understand what you mean by "file type preset like file sorting", but Meld is a great tool for comparing files and folders.

1. Does *not* have addons.
2. Does folder compare
3. Is open source

---

[image: meld screenshot]

Comment: I'm aware of meld and it doesn't have the feature that I need the most (plugins).Please see my updated question o understand what I mean